QGIS Snapping not working for move and copy feature
I use the Move & copy feature from the advanced digitized panel and would like to stitch two lines together, which are in the same layer. Regrettably, the snapping tool seems to not work at all.

QGIS snapping not working for me
As you can see in the image below. I should have seen the pink box just next to the existing line within 5px area, but it doesn't appear. The lines aren't stitched together at all. I tried to fiddle with options and chose segment instead of vertex - the same.
Is there any option to make it work for the Move & copy feature?

I don't think it is possible at the moment. It would require that the lines are already perfectly at the same parallel way? E.g. if the other line is directed to opposite direction, what should happen? The intersection of the lines should snap?

If you are happy that the line snaps to the middle segment, then 1. check that your QGIS setup has snapping settings on. Then check that you are using the tolerance tool: in the middle of the segment. If the line does not have any vertexes in the middle of the line, there should be a purple triangle appearing.

Does it help to specify a "type" that you want to snap to (e.g. snap to points, line segments, ...)? It is the symbol third from the left in the "Advanced digitizing symbol" toolbar.
